# What could be causing "...does not recognize...errors on code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

I'm following a tutorial using Visual Studio Code online, but when it tells me to paste

dotnet new webapp -f net6.0

into the command prompt, it tells me:

dotnet new webapp -f net6.0
dotnet : The term 'dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- dotnet new webapp -f net6.0
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dotnet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I followed the tutorial instructions to a "T" but it still gives me this error.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you install the [.NET 6 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)? Did you log out/log in or restart your computer to force it to reload your PATH variable?

Comment: Note that I've removed the C# and ASP.NET tags from your question as they are not relevant. I've added the correct tags of dotnet-cli and visual-studio-code.

Comment: You can install the .Net from power shell command : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script